# Handling optional arguments

Tags: arguments

This function makes a new named buffer that can run shell commands.  But it only works properly when no argument is passed.  When an argument is passed or set through the interactive clause, I would like that the buffer name takes the argument value for the name rather than the current `(generate-new-buffer-name "foo")`.

```
(defun galaxy-shell (&optional bufrnm)
  "TODO"

  (interactive "s Buffer_name: ")

  (let ( (bufrnm (generate-new-buffer-name "foo")) )
    (shell bufrnm)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(generate-new-buffer-name (or bufrnm "foo"))
```

Comment: How does the `or` part work?

Comment: What does the documentation for `or` say?

Comment: Returns `bufrnm` if it is non-nill, else return `foo`.  Not much resemblance to a `logical or`.

Comment: Logical or bitwise or is a much more niche operator. A programmer can go their whole lives without needing it, but boolean or is much more widely used. Elisp does have `logor` should you ever need it. If you pay attention, you will notice that most languages make the same choice to separate them. C has `||` for boolean or and `|` for bitwise or, for example, but the one you use most often has more characters to type.